# C# - RegEx - Get Strings Between Two Lines

Tags: c#, regex, text, match

I've been battling with this question for a couple of days now.

**Question:** How can I pull multiple strings that match my search criteria between two lines in C#?

Here is my current process:

1. Read all lines of a file.

   ```
   text_file = "C:\test.txt";
   string[] file_text = File.ReadAllLines(text_file);
   ```
2. Loop through each line of the file and search for matches

   ```
   foreach (string line in file_text)
   {
       Regex r1 = new Regex(@"Processor\(s\):\s+.+\n\s+(.+)\nBIOS Version:");

       Match match1 = r1.Match(line);

       if (match1.Success)
       {
           string processor = match1.Groups[1].Value;
           // Just to see if I matched anything
           System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(processor);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Here is the example text:

   ```
   Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                              [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel ~2826 Mhz
   BIOS Version:              Phoenix Technologies LTD 6.00, 7/30/2013
   ```

**Problem:** I used the website "RegExr" and "Regex101" which shows that the processor name should be captured in "Groups[1]" but nothing appears to be captured when I attempt to dump it to a message box.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You read the files into a line array, and use a regex to match several lines. This is impossible that way. If you want to read a whole file in, read it all into a variable, and use your regex on the whole text with newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to read all of the file into a single string variable and then run the Regex against that:

```
text_file = "C:\test.txt";
string file_text = File.ReadAllText(text_file);

Regex r1 = new Regex(@"Processor\(s\):\s+.+\n\s+(.+)\nBIOS Version:");

Match match1 = r1.Match(file_text);
```

Comment: Thank you! I followed Wiktor and your advice and I'm able to pull data! The only problem I'm facing is that it only grabs one match, instead of all the matches. Trying to figure that out now.